# ASP.net not displaying CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net

My Index.cshtml page looks like this

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <link href="~/Content/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
</head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title text-center">Master/Detail</h1>
        <div class="md-container">
            <div class="col-3 master">
                <div class="master-item active-item" onclick="select(this)">Option 1</div>
                <div class="master-item" onclick="select(this)">Option 2</div>
                <div class="master-item" onclick="select(this)">Option 3</div>
                <div class="master-item" onclick="select(this)">Option 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 detail">
                <button id="back-btn" class="hidden-md" onclick="back()">< Back</button>
                <h1 class="detail-title text-center">Option 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

This is my project structure

I have tried adding @Url.Content after the `<link href` tag but that didn't help.
The website doesen't display any CSS at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my Visual studio isn't recognizing the folder "Content" that I made. After I moved the "index.css" file into the deafault "css" folder and changed the path to there it started working.